# Why is this Cloud Firestore security rule suddenly failing?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

For some time I was using the following rule for Cloud Firestore in my Flutter project:

"You can see chats if you're logged in, a member and the chat was not flagged".

```
match /chats/{chatId} {
  allow read: if signedIn() && request.auth.uid in resource.data.members && resource.data.flagged == false;
}
```

It used to work and to me, it seems correct. But recently, it started to fail. When I use only

```
allow read: if signedIn();
```

It works just fine. Any idea what might be the problem? In the Firebase emulator, I can see it also fails, but there is no explanation. Obviously, `members` and `flagged` fields exist (when a chat document is available).

Could this have happened after updating a particular package, like `cloud_firestore`?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found out, finally, what was wrong. According to this [page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions), "the result set should satisfy the rule's condition". However, I thought my query was exactly the same as my rule and I didn't know what was wrong.

It turns out, this is taken quite literally.

In my query I had:

`where('flagged', isNotEqualTo: true)` and my rule was `flagged == false`. I needed to change that to `flagged != true`. This is very confusing. It seems like a bug to me, and otherwise, I would be very curious to know the reason behind this.